# Query Cypher node A does not have relation with node B with conditions on B

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to build a Cypher to check if node A does not have a relation with a node B with specific attributes

```
node (A) 
does not have relation (X)
with node (B) where B.date > 5
```

I've tried this and fails if there are relations with B nodes where B.date = 3

```
START u = node:users("id:123123") 
MATCH (u)-[r1?:X]->(e1) 
WHERE (NOT ((e1.date! > 5)))
OR r1 IS NULL 
RETURN (u), e1
```

I'm using Neo4j 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check every node B that is related to A, and only if none of them has attribute date that satisfies B.date > 5, then the A is the desired node.

```
Start u = node:users("id:123123")
Match u-[:DEPENDS_ON]->e1
With u, collect(e1) as ecol
Where None (e in ecol where e.date > 5) 
RETURN (u), ecol
```